# Trying to split csv column data into lists after reading in using pandas library

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file containing 3 columns of data: column 1 = time vector, column 2 is untuned circuit response and column 3 is the tuned circuit response.
I am reading in this csv data in python using pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter = ",")
```

I am now trying to create 3 lists, 1 list for each column of data. I have tried the following but not working as lists end up empty:

```
for col in df:
    time.append(col[0])
    untuned.append(col[1])
    tuned.append(col[2])
```

Can anyone give me some help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas series tolist method:

```
time = df['time vector'].tolist()
untuned = df['untuned circuit'].tolist()
tuned = df['tuned circuit'].tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, if your use case it to just get it in lists, use `csvreader`. It reduces a lot of overhead.

```
import csv

time = list()
untuned = list()
tuned = list()

with open("filename.csv") as csv_data_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_data_file, delimiter=",")
    for each_row in csv_reader:
        time.append(each_row[0])
        untuned.append(each_row[1])
        tuned.append(each_row[2])
```

If you have other use cases that require pandas or that your file is large and you require the power of pandas, use `.tolist()` as suggested by @Bruno Mello.

You can also use an iterator.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    time.append(row[0])
    untuned.append(row[1])
    tuned.append(row[2])
```